# Trouble using ScreenManager to display two screens with Kivy & Python. Getting a black screen

Tags: python, kivy

Please excuse the messy code -- novice coder here. I'm trying to have two screens: one with a gridlayout and another blank. Every button on the gridlayout screen should send the user to the blank screen for now. Eventually I want to have each button's label replaced by the user with an entry field on screen2. I'm also using a for loop in the python file to create my gridlayout and label the buttons accordingly.

My issue is when I run the file it compiles but gives a black screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def makeGrid(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 12)
        flipper = 6
        m = 2
        for r in range(1,17):
            flipper = flipper * -1
            subt = 6 + flipper
            offset = m%2
            for c in range(1,13):
                cols = abs(c-subt) + offset 
                btn = Button(text=(str(r)+ '.'+ str(cols)))
                layout.add_widget(btn)
            m += 1
        return layout

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass
        
class DraftBoardApp(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        DraftBoardApp.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_1'))
        DraftBoardApp.sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='screen_2'))
        return DraftBoardApp.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DraftBoardApp().run()
```

My .kv file is effectively empty right now besides

```
<Screen_One>:
<Screen_Two>:
```

Comment: You haven't initialised the `Screen`s.

Comment: I dont think you should add widget in your App class. Insteads, create another class with (screenmanager) and return that class in your App class.

Comment: @ApuCoder Sorry would you mind showing me how to do this and explain a little further?

Answer (score 0):

The `ScreenOne` has not been [initialised (initialized)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) anywhere in your posted code, that's why you didn't see the widgets. The method `makeGrid` is just a regular method defined in this class. To make things work you either define everything within the default [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) (but don't return anything) or, call the method `makeGrid` there to add the returned instance.

Thus the first approach is something like this,

```py
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Make sure you didn't override any
        # superclass rule by calling super on this.
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Define, add etc. whatever you need.
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 12)
        flipper = 6
        m = 2
        for r in range(1,17):
            flipper = flipper * -1
            subt = 6 + flipper
            offset = m%2
            for c in range(1,13):
                cols = abs(c-subt) + offset 
                btn = Button(text=(str(r)+ '.'+ str(cols)))
                layout.add_widget(btn)
            m += 1
        # Don't forget to add to this.
        self.add_widget(layout)
```

As a side note, in the method `build` instead of accessing the App's subclass (i.e. here `DraftBoardApp`) directly you should've modified its instance as,

```
self.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_1'))
```

instead of

```
DraftBoardApp.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_1'))
```

etc.